# синтаксическая ошибка | https c#

Tags: c#, webclient

нашел видео о том как скачивать файлы с сервера. вот код. там какая то ошибка. ниже скрин. Если запускаю дебаг в самом вижуал студио, то он работает, а если запускаю в папке, то ничего не работает.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.DownloadFile
                ("paragonproject.ru/dlc_files/revolver_2/dlc.rpf",
                @"C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\dlc.rpf"); // paragonproject.ru/dlc_files/revolver_2/dlc.rpf
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст со скрина
Изначально это исключение было создано в этом стеке вызовов:
[Внешний код]

Comment: Ну а схему кто за вас добавит? http/https

Comment: `WebClient` устарел, и очень давно, используйте `HttpClient`.